# The Android OS has a way to lock the screen orientation at the OS level. Is there a way to do this in code?

Tags: android

Android 7.1.1 and onwards has a weird bug where screens locked in a given orientation will start at the wrong orientation for ~.5s if the phone is in that orientation before going to the right orientation. But if you lock the phone in an orientation at the OS level this won't happen. Is there a way to do this through code?

Comment: no, you can only lock orientation for your app

Comment: So there's no way to get rid of the .5s in the wrong orientation?